# Transfer data from one workbook to another using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to transfer data from "Finalinputsheet" to a new workbook named "Mydata" this is the code that I've tried for the columns which i want to transfer to a new workbook

```
Sub transfer()
Dim MyData As Workbook
Dim DataWs As Worksheet
Dim myWs As Worksheet
Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FinalinputFile")
Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("D:\Desktop\My\MyData.xlsx")
Set DataWs = MyData.Sheets("Data")
myWs.Range("C3:C11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FinalinputFile")
Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("D:\Desktop\My\MyData.xlsx")
Set DataWs = MyData.Sheets("Data")
myWs.Range("E3:E11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("F2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll




MyData.Save

End Sub
```

I have tried this but it doesn't give me an output not sure where I've gone wrong

[image: This is the sheet image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your not getting an output because all your code is mostly doing is selecting a range and getting the column count. The code below should do the trick. Just change the pathway for the file.

```
Sub transfer()
Dim MyData As Workbook
Dim DataWs As Worksheet
dim myWs as Worksheet
set myWs = thisworkbook.sheets("FinalinputFile")
Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("D:\Desktop\Data.xlsx")
Set DataWs = MyData.Sheets("Sheet1")
Myws.Range("C3:C440").Copy
DataWs.Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

MyData.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a runtime error " subscript out of range"

Comment: Edited the answer try now sorry.

Comment: where should i paste this code? in "data" workbook or the other workbook from where the data is coming?

Comment: This is based on where the data is coming from.try it there and if it works but you want it the other way around just change the reference in the code.

Comment: worked fine mate! thanks for your immediate response! :)

Comment: This code won't work if I want to copy multiple column data and transfer it to another workbook?

Comment: Hi no the code above is was design to copy 1 column, but you should be able to modify it to copy multiple columns e.g. `sourceWS.Range("A1:B20").Copy` then `destWS.Range("E5").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` etc.. or copy each column individually then paste or use a loop depending on your pattern.

Comment: I want to copy only some columns  at the same time ....for example.. Column  ",E ,G, I,K... And so on

Comment: If they are all the same size range I suggest you have a look at `Union` method. e.g. `Union(rng1,rng2,rng3).copy` but you will need to show us your code and what you have tried. If you get stuck we can help you then. If you do get stuck I suggest create another question. Since this question has already been answered based on the original question.

Comment: Okay I'll try and then update the question accordingly

Comment: I have updated the code that i tried for copying multiple columns....is it possible to make this code shorter?

Comment: Hi I suggest you roll back to the original question and create a new question as the current answer does not match the question anymore. As I mentioned on my previous comment to have a look at `Union` method and try it. Stackoverflow expects you to try solve your own problem first and if you get stuck we can help you.