# Transfer multiple columns from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I want to transfer multiple columns to a new workbook named "My data" to a specified respective columns. I've tried this code but its too long and i want to try to make it short and once the process is completed i want to close the new work book not sure how to do that as well.

```
Sub transfer()
Dim MyData As Workbook
Dim DataWs As Worksheet
Dim myWs As Worksheet
Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FinalinputFile")
Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("D:\Desktop\My\MyData.xlsx")
Set DataWs = MyData.Sheets("Data")
myWs.Range("C3:C11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FinalinputFile")
Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("D:\Desktop\My\MyData.xlsx")
Set DataWs = MyData.Sheets("Data")
myWs.Range("E3:E11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("F2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FinalinputFile")
Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("D:\Desktop\My\MyData.xlsx")
Set DataWs = MyData.Sheets("Data")
myWs.Range("G3:G11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("G2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FinalinputFile")
Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("D:\Desktop\My\MyData.xlsx")
Set DataWs = MyData.Sheets("Data")
myWs.Range("I3:I11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("H2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FinalinputFile")
Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("D:\Desktop\My\MyData.xlsx")
Set DataWs = MyData.Sheets("Data")
myWs.Range("K3:K11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("I2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FinalinputFile")
Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("D:\Desktop\My\MyData.xlsx")
Set DataWs = MyData.Sheets("Data")
myWs.Range("M3:M11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("J2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll


Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FinalinputFile")
Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("D:\Desktop\My\MyData.xlsx")
Set DataWs = MyData.Sheets("Data")
myWs.Range("U3:U11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("M2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll


  MyData.Save

  End Sub
```

Comment: Lol did you create a new account? Just a coincidence that this has the exact same [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54086935/transfer-data-from-one-workbook-to-another-using-vba/54087188?noredirect=1#comment95046351_54087188)?

Comment: had to man! they didnt allow me to post another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code

```
Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FinalinputFile")
Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("D:\Desktop\My\MyData.xlsx")
Set DataWs = MyData.Sheets("Data")
```

Is repeated even thought it's the same every time, your code should be just fine without it, so you can shorten it by removing the repetitions.

Also, the code for closing the workbook is `Workbooks("MyData").Close` but you would have to save it, and it's better to call the full name like `Workbooks("MyData").Save`

So your final code would look something like

```
Sub transfer()
Dim MyData As Workbook
Dim DataWs As Worksheet
Dim myWs As Worksheet
Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FinalinputFile")
Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("D:\Desktop\My\MyData.xlsx")
Set DataWs = MyData.Sheets("Data")

myWs.Range("C3:C11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
myWs.Range("E3:E11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("F2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
myWs.Range("G3:G11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("G2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
myWs.Range("I3:I11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("H2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
myWs.Range("K3:K11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("I2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
myWs.Range("M3:M11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("J2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
myWs.Range("U3:U11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("M2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 

Workbooks("MyData").Save
Workbooks("MyData").Close

End Sub
```

Comment: if i want to create a new excel workbook and then transfer the data what should i add to this code?

Comment: Set MyData = Workbooks.Add, and change the Save and Close methods to use the variable MyData. Also, It would be MyData.SaveAs("<path>")

Comment: i am not sure if i got you

Answer (score 0):

## Paste Column Ranges

### Highlights

- Assigned all values to constants.
- Added workbook open check.
- Reduced object references to one worksheet.
- Replaced Copy/Paste with Copy (Destination).

Adjust the values in the constants section to fit your needs.

### The Code

```
Sub transfer()

    ' Source
    Const cSource As Variant = "FinalinputFile"   ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cSFirst As Integer = 3                  ' First Row Number
    Const cLast As Integer = 11000                ' Last Row Number
    Const cSCols As String = "C,E,G,I,K,M,U"      ' Column List
    ' Target
    Const cPath As String = "D:\Desktop\My\"      ' Workbook Path
    Const cName As String = "MyData.xlsx"         ' Workbook Name
    Const cTarget As Variant = "Data"             ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cTFirst As Integer = 2                  ' First Row Number
    Const cTCols As String = "E,F,G,H,I,J,M"      ' Column List

    Dim DataWs As Worksheet   ' Target Worksheet
    Dim vntS As Variant       ' Source Column Array
    Dim vntT As Variant       ' Target Column Array
    Dim i As Integer          ' Columns Counter

    ' Check if Target Workbook is already open.
    For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count
        If Workbooks(i).Name = cName Then Exit For
    Next

    ' Create reference to Target Worksheet.
    If i > Workbooks.Count Then ' Target Workbook is not open.
        Set DataWs = Workbooks.Open(cPath & cName).Worksheets(cTarget)
      Else                      ' Target Workbook is open.
        Set DataWs = Workbooks(i).Worksheets(cTarget)
    End If

    ' Write Column Lists into Column Arrays.
    vntS = Split(cSCols, ",")
    vntT = Split(cTCols, ",")

    ' Copy Source Column Ranges to Target Columns Ranges.
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cSource)
        For i = 0 To UBound(vntS) ' or Ubound(vntT) - it's the same.
            .Range(.Cells(cSFirst, vntS(i)), .Cells(cLast, vntS(i))).Copy _
            DataWs.Cells(cTFirst, vntT(i))
        Next
    End With

    ' Save and close Target Workbook using Parent property.
    With DataWs.Parent
        .Close True ' True saves the workbook.
    End With

    Set DataWs = Nothing

End Sub
```